# How to specify exact sheet on Google Sheets API node.js batchUpdate request

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api

I want to add an empty row above all data on the second sheet but can't understand how to specify the exact sheet. Now empty row adding to the first sheet.

```js
const request = {
    spreadsheetId: 'spreadsheetId',

    resource: {
      requests:[
        {
          insertRange: {
            range: {
              startRowIndex: 0,
              endRowIndex: 1
            },
            shiftDimension: 'ROWS'
          }
        }
    ]
  },
};

 try{
  const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request);
}catch(err){ console.log(err)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification point:

- In this answer, at first, the sheet ID is retrieved from the 2nd sheet using the method of get, and then, the method of batchUpdate is requested using the retrieved sheet ID.

When this point is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
const res = (await sheets.spreadsheets.get({spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, fields: "sheets(properties(sheetId))"})).data;  // Added
const sheetIdOf2ndSheet = res.sheets[1].properties.sheetId;  // Added

const request = {
  spreadsheetId: 'spreadsheetId',
  resource: {
    requests: [
      {
        insertRange: {
          range: {
            sheetId: sheetIdOf2ndSheet,  // Added
            startRowIndex: 0,
            endRowIndex: 1,
          },
          shiftDimension: "ROWS",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

try {
  const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

#### Note:

- Of course, when you want to search the sheet ID from the sheet name, it can be also achieved.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: @NeoN Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.